# error: request for member ‘board’ in ‘connect’, which is of non-class type ‘game*’

Tags: c++

When I tried to compile my code, it report error:request for member ‘board’ in ‘connect’, which is of non-class type ‘game’,
I don't know how to figure it out...
This is my code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include<cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    struct game{
       char **board;
       int r, c, p;
       char p1;
       char p2;
    };

    char * is_valid_arguments(int, char *info[]);
    void set_game_info(game *, char *info[]);
    char** creat_table(int, int);
    void play_game(game *);
    bool check_winner(game);
    void delete_table(game *);
    //Prototypes, some of them is not included since haven't been finished...

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
       int row, col, piece;
       game* connect=NULL;

       is_valid_arguments(argc, argv); //This is to check if the input is valid, it works, so we don't have to check this function
       row=atoi(argv[2]);
       col=atoi(argv[4]);
       piece=atoi(argv[6]);

       creat_table(row, col);
       connect.board=creat_table(row,col);//I thought to give the result of this function to connect.board, but it report that error
    return 0;
    }
char *is_valid_arguments(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int flag1=0;
   string r, c, p;
   if (argc!=7){
      cout<<"Too few arguments."<<endl;
      exit(0);
   }
   r=argv[1];
   c=argv[3];
   p=argv[5];
   if (r != "-r"||c!="-c"||p!="-p"){
      cout<<"Invalid options."<<endl;
      exit(0);
   }
   while (flag1==0){
      if (atoi(argv[2])<=0){
     cout<<"Please input positive row number."<<endl;
     cin>>argv[2];
      }
      else if (atoi(argv[4])<=0){
     cout<<"Please input positive column number."<<endl;
     cin>>argv[4];
      }
      else if (atoi(argv[6])<=0){
     cout<<"Please input positive piece number."<<endl;
     cin>>argv[6];
      }
      else {
     flag1=1;
      }
   }
}

char** creat_table(int row, int col){
   char **table;
   table=new char*[row];
   for (int i=0; i<row;i++){
      table[i]=new char[col];
   }//create the table
   for(int i=0; i<row;i++){
      for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
     table[i][j]=' ';
     cout<<table[i][j]<<"| ";
      }//give a " " to each element of the table
      cout<<endl;
   }

   return table;
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: You likely want `game connect;` (note no star)

Comment: What does `is_valid_arguments` return? Why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: If I cancel that star, it gives me another error:  error: conversion from ‘long int’ to non-scalar type ‘game’ requested. And about the is_valid_arguments, it doesn't return anything, I should have used void... but it doesn't matter, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `connect->board` instead of `connect.board` and initialize the board first.

Or change `game *connect=NULL;` to `game connect;` and also do not forget initialize the board.